# Do blog titles that exceed the recommended amount for title tags hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, blog

Some of our blog posts on the company site get flagged in Moz Site Crawl as having title tags with more characters than recommended.

Does this hurt SEO? My thinking is that since blog titles are often on the long-tail side, the negative impact of a Moz crawl error is outweighed by the keywords and voice in the original blog title.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are confusing two separate concepts. Title length has to do with managing SERP links for CTR (click through rate). I recommend following title length recommendations.

Comment: Google may index your title fully(with exceed length) on their [caffiene](https://googleblog.blogspot.in/2010/06/our-new-search-index-caffeine.html) indexer but they might just show only limits character in search result pages for better user experience. So closetnoc is right. But keyword position on title might affect SEO very little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommended to have a title length up to 60 characters in order to make it fully visible for user (not truncated) in search results. You can also put your important keywords at the beginning of the title, so that it will give them a slighty more value.

Answer (score 2):

If the Title is too long for Google to display, it will truncate what it shows, or choose something else that the algorithm 'figures out' to show.

Keeping the Title within the suggested recommended character limit allows Google to display what you have written without any issues.

Having your Title show up exactly as you have written it allows you have more control over what will be displayed, hopefully increasing the CTR.

Comment: Thanks, I think your last point backs up my thinking (or bias!) well.